# Is it possible capture Windows System audio via Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-recording

Is there is way to capture windows system audio using JavaScript. I want to record those audio which is played in windows 10 System outside browser. So is there any way to record those channel in multiple channel.

Comment: There are ways to capture the microphone inside browser, but capturing system sounds I would expect would come under a security blanket, and even if possible would require user intervention, in the same way as mic & camera.

Comment: is there is way like installing adapter or driver through which i can access audio ?

Comment: can you please explain what is way or share some information  where it require  user intervention. I have to access the audio from system as per my project requirement.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in browser extenstion ?

Comment: I don't think so,.  Here is a link to what your can do with Web Audio -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API